# Bug with __int128_t in Clang?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, int128

This little code compiles with both GCC and Clang, but gives different results:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  __int128_t test=10;
  while(test>0){
    int myTest=(int)test;
    printf("? %d\n", myTest);
    test--;
  }

}
```

With GCC this counts from 10 down to 1, the intended behaviour, while for Clang it keeps on counting into negative numbers.  With Clang, if I replace `test--` with `test-=1` then it gives the expected behaviour as well.

__int128_t is a GCC extension, so the above results only apply to non-standard C, so maybe __int128_t is "use at your own risk" in Clang.

Is this a bug in Clang, or did I make some mistake I'm not seeing?

**EDIT:** I'm using gcc (MacPorts gcc48 4.8-20130411_0) 4.8.1 20130411 (prerelease) and Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn).

Comment: Right, this does just what you explained on OS X 10.7.5 with GCC 4.2 and Clang 4.0.

Comment: Works fine here on my machine, "Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)".

Comment: @Carl Maybe Apple fixed it between clang-421.0.60 and clang-425.0.28. I should update to check.

Comment: Seems that way, yup.  clang is all open-source, so I'm sure you can hunt down the patch if you really want to.

Comment: I think the updates come through the Mac App Store these days.

Comment: @Carl Yes your right. Apparently I wasn't getting Xcode updates [because I had Spotlight disabled on Macintosh HD](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2794280?start=15&tstart=0). I updated Xcode and the command line tools to Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn) and now the code works properly with Clang.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a bug in Clang, which was resolved somewhere between Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn) and Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn), see the comments -- thanks Carl and H2CO3.